# Android: declaring Activity variable that encloses several specific Activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities which both call one class. `isCalledFromCreate` is initiated in constructor of the class, determining from which activity the class is called. Usually, we would have to do this

```
if (calledFromCreate) {
    ((DoAction) context).askForLocationPermission(params);
} else {
    ((MakeAction) context).askForLocationPermission(params);
}
```

for every call in the class, resulting in code duplication. However, if the methods in both activities are named the same with same parameters, is there a way to combine both Activities into one that would be still capable of calling activity-specific methods? With this in mind, I would like to create shorted code from the one above as `((MakeAction)context).askForLocationPermission(params);`without the need to duplicate code, where `(MagicActivity) context` would be the activity that encloses both `DoAction` and `MakeAction`.

Comment: Create an abstract base Activity handling the permission for both of them. Add abstract method to handle the specific permission call checker. Then each activity need to be derived from the base Activity.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך could you please provide a code for this? Don't fully understand what you mean with handling the permission and call checkers